# Multiple line output from execlp

Tags: c++, exec

I am trying to return a multiple line output using execlp but am unsure of the exact method to do so. I have tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string str = "echo ";
   str += "one \n";
   str += "two \n";
   str += "three \n";
   if(execl("/bin/sh","/bin/sh","-c",str.c_str(),(char*)NULL) == -1)
   {
      printf("Child Execution Failed\n");
      exit(1); 
   }                
   exit(0);
   return 0;
}
```

I basically want all of `one`, `two` and `three` to be printed in the shell. I get the following output though

```
one
/bin/sh: 2: two: not found
/bin/sh: 3: three: not found
```

Many thanks again!

**Answer:** Found a simple answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string str = "echo one\n";
   str += "echo two\n";
   str += "echo three\n";

   if(execl("/bin/sh","/bin/sh","-c",str.c_str(),(char*)NULL) == -1)
   {
      printf("Child Execution Failed\n");
      exit(1); 
   }                
   exit(0);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am using `dup2()` to send information received from `execlp()` to the socket created. Do you think that could create some issues? Sorry for not being clear, but I didn't think that could be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

`execlp` replaces the current process that calls it with the program specified in `execlp` arguments.  See the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) and note:

> The `exec()` family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

Having a loop trying to call `execlp` many times is pointless, as after the first call to `execlp`, your program is no longer executing.  There are ways to use `execlp` in combination with [`fork`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) or one of fork's variants) that can work, but there are easier options...

Instead, use [`popen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to run a distinct child process and have a pipe to read its output from.

Comment: thanks but would running the program in the second method defined above also be incorrect?

Comment: It depends what you mean by *"I only get the first name from the userdb table"*.  When you use `execlp` and it takes over your calling process, that process can't "get" anything back as it's no longer executing.  On the other hand, the new process running `/bin/sh` can output stuff to the terminal, which *might* be all you want for your current purposes.

Comment: the `userdb` table setup in server has about 10 entries but only the first of them is sent to client side when `execlp()` is used with `fork()`, and `dup2()` on socket created between server and client. The other entries are printed on the server side as `/bin/sh: 2: user2: not found`. I am trying to print/send the entire userdb list at the client side

Comment: stackoverflow policy on asking questions requires them to provide minimal, complete code that still reproduces the problem.  Having snippets of your code that miss important parts - like that you are using fork and sockets - wastes the time of those answering with warnings about potential problems you don't actually have, and as the devil is often if the detail, it's impractical to comment on all the possible problems in the code not presented.  Anyway, I suggest you write some code to read from the socket, then you can at least verify that you're doing that properly, then use the data read.

Comment: I am sorry, didn't mean to waste your time. Would see that such things wouldn't be repeated again. Sincere apologies for the inconvenience caused again

Comment: No worries - I'm not upset - just explaining that this process isn't going to work very efficiently unless you present the question well.  I do hope you can get to the bottom of it and am happy to help - just hard to do so with the question as is.

Comment: thank you for being patient! the socket is working just fine as I could see the communication happening between server and client side just as expected, as long as I don't involve sending strings which have `\n` character in it - in which case only the sub-string up until the `\n` is being sent when using `echo string` as argument in `execlp`.

Comment: You could try writing the input to a file, then using `cat` instead of `echo`, or carefully quoting and escaping.  The code you've posted seems to be inserting newlines, which suggests it's still an issue.  (Apologies in advance if I don't respond to further comments quickly - got a nasty hangover and it's 5am here).